# Convert SQL Query To Use Set Operators

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to complete a SQL Query (Oracle) using a Set Operator, but I am struggling to understand how it would be implemented.

Schema:

```
Customer (ID, firstName, lastName)       - PrimaryKey: ID
Transaction (code, type, date, amount)   - PrimaryKey: code 
performs(code*, ID*)                     - PrimaryKey: code - ForeignKey: ID
```

The query needs to display the Customer.ID of people have have complete one or less transactions. I can complete this by using the following:

```
SELECT C.ID
FROM CUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN PERFORMS P
ON C.ID = P.ID
INNER JOIN TRANSACTION T
ON T.CODE = P.CODE
GROUP BY C.ID
HAVING COUNT(T.CODE) <= 1;
```

But, I am struggling to work out how to use a Set Operator to achieve the same thing. I believe I should be using INTERSECT.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: my bet is on course work. and you missed the database tag

Comment: Why? there is no reason to use a set operator here. JOIN/IN/EXISTS are the default choices here

Comment: @haytem bec the teacher wants to teach a lesson what they do?

Comment: wrong edit, not a tag `database`, `oracle` would be the right chioce

Comment: @Aツ Yep, it is for a tutorial, and I am struggling to understand why / how I would use the Set Operators to complete this. Database tag added.

Comment: well, next step: your query is not correct. you use inner joins which display only customer which have at least one transaction. with your having part you'll exclude all with more than one transaction. which means you display only customer which have exactly one transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not how you'd normally do this, but as an exercise, you can get the set of all customer IDs, and MINUS the set of all IDs with more than two transactions, which you can get without looking at the customer table a second time:

```
SELECT C.ID
FROM CUSTOMER C
MINUS
SELECT P.ID
FROM PERFORMS P
INNER JOIN TRANSACTION T
ON T.CODE = P.CODE
GROUP BY P.ID
HAVING COUNT(T.CODE) > 1;
```

You don't really need to join to TRANSACTION, you can just count the code values in PERFORMS directly:

```
SELECT C.ID
FROM CUSTOMER C
MINUS
SELECT P.ID
FROM PERFORMS P
GROUP BY P.ID
HAVING COUNT(P.CODE) > 1;
```

... but maybe there's more to the question what you've shown, like restricting by type or date.

Comment: Thank you for the help! it makes perfect sense now I can see it in action!